# MySQL SELECT fails without LIMIT

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm connecting to a MySQL server with the node jdbc package. The purpose is to duplicate data from an old AS400 into a MySQL server for more advanced querying.

My connection string looks like this: `jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/db_name?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false`.

I'm able to use the connection normally to truncate and insert records for the cache. I can select from the table if I include a `LIMIT`, but when I try to retrieve the data with the below sql I get the following error.

`select * from table_name;`

Complete error output:

```
node:internal/process/promises:218
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[Error: Error running instance method
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,756,928 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,756,972 milliseconds ago.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1202)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,756,928 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,756,972 milliseconds ago.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:519)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:683)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:622)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:970)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:916)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:660)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1170)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:513)
        ... 10 more
] {
  cause: nodeJava_com_mysql_cj_jdbc_exceptions_CommunicationsException {}
}
```

Any help in clarifying why this is happening would be helpful and most appreciated!

Comment: How many rows are in the table? If there's a huge number then you might be hitting a timeout somewhere.

Comment: I limited it for testing, so it's only 30 rows currently.

Comment: Just discovered that if I set the limit to anything greater than 1 it also fails in the same way